# How to access previous values inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, string, loops, counter

I'm kinda new to JS programming and I'm sorry if this is an obvious question. I have a code that counts the repeated letters in a string. The code should only output the letters that are used more than twice.

For example:

```js
let str = "HELLOWORLD"
```

Output should be : `L = 3, O = 3`

My code outputs: `L =3, O = 2, O =2, L = 3`

I wanted to get rid of the second O and L.

```
function repeat(){
    let str = "helloworld";
    let letters = "";
    let count = "";
    let output = "";
    let x = "";
    for (i = 0; i <str.length; i++){
    letters = str.charAt(i); 
    count = str.split(letters).length - 1;
    if (count >= 2 && x !== letters) {
    output += letters +"=" + count + " ";
    }
    x = letters;
}
console.log(output);
}

repeat();
```

I can only remove a duplicate letter if it comes before the new one because of the `x = letters;` code. I would like the characters to appear only once,  but I'm having a hard time with the loops. I know it looks messy and needs improvement, but i'll work on it after I figure out my solution. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: More than twice, or twice or more. Your output does reflect your description.

Comment: so my current output is l=3, o=3, l=3(again)
I wanted to get rid of duplicate letters since it's already been counted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep repeated letters in an array and then check if the letter already exists.

```
function repeat(){
    let str = "helloworld";
    let letters = "";
    let count = "";
    let output = "";
    let x = "";
    let multipleChars = [];
    for (i = 0; i <str.length; i++){
    letters = str.charAt(i);
    count = str.split(letters).length - 1;
    if (count >= 2 && x !== letters && !multipleChars.includes(letters)) {
    output += letters +"=" + count + " ";
    multipleChars.push(letters);
    }
    x = letters;
}
console.log(output);
}

repeat();
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir! This is what I was trying to do.
I also tried inserting each letter in the array earlier but I had a hard time returning the values.
I added the x = letters in the end because i thought it would work as variable where it stores the previous letter. It worked for a duplicate letters letter that beside each other (he*LL*oworld) but still counts the L at the end before the D. Thank you so much again sir for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: If it is useful you can keep this answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var strs = "helloworld";

const output = strs.split('').reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  prev[cur] = (prev[cur] || 0) + 1;
  return prev;
}, {});

const convertToArray = Object.entries(output);
const filterMorethan2 = convertToArray.filter(([key, value]) => value >= 2);

const converBackObj = Object.fromEntries(filterMorethan2);
console.log(converBackObj)
```

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'll try to play with this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

One common method is to use [an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object) to maintain a count of the letters - the letters are the property keys, and the value is the number that gets increased whenever that letter is found. We can then [loop over that object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and log only those properties where the value is greater than 2.

```js
function repeat(str) {

  // Create the object
  const obj = {};

  // Loop over the string
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    const letter = str[i];

    // If the letter (key) doesn't already exist
    // on the object create it, and set the value to zero
    // then immediately increase it by one
    if (obj[letter] === undefined) {
      obj[letter] = 0;
    }

    obj[letter] += 1;

  }

  // So we have an object that contains _all_ the
  // letters, so now we loop over it to print out
  // only those with values greater than two
  // We can use a template string:
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
  for (let letter in obj) {
    if (obj[letter] > 2) {
      console.log(`${letter} = ${obj[letter]}`);
    }  
  }

}

repeat('helloworld');
```

Comment: Thank you Andy for the detailed approach, this looks advanced to me but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it a little simpler to understand, and added some links to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

using your js toolbox:

```js
let str = 'HelloWorld';

let a = Object.entries([...str].reduce((r,c)=>{
  r[c]=(r[c] || 0) +1;
  return r;
},{})).filter(e=>e[1]>2).sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a).reduce((s,i,idx)=>(`${s}${idx>0 ? ", " : ""}${i.join('=')}`),'');

console.log(a);
```